# Communicate to http server from AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a requirement to connect to another server via https, from an iSeries system. I am unfamiliar with web service programming on this platform. Understanding that IBM i OS presents a somewhat unique environment, that most developers outside our community are unfamiliar with, what should I use to communicate with the destination server over http from an AS400 type system?

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've used [Scott Klement's code](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/tutorial.html) to communicate with different servers.

Comment: This question should not be on hold. It makes sense to those of us who are IBM midrange professionals. And we are answering it in a way that makes sense to those who have such a question. The tags shown on the profiles of those who held this question leads me to believe that they have little or no experience working in an IBM midrange environment. Please open this question back up to those of us who do.

Comment: @user please review my edits and add additional details or corrections as needed.

Comment: As @WarrenT has said, this question should not be closed. Those of us familiar with the IBM i (ibm-midrange) knew exactly what the question meant - thus JamesA's answer and my comment with multiple links to various resources.

Comment: I voted to reopen.  Would like OP to clarify by editing the question to add details of the nature of the business processes at work here.  Unfortunately, there is still a group of midrangers totally unfamiliar with web programming and have no idea what sort of questions to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what HLL you are using but the [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) library can be used from Java and from RPGLE to perform http communications.

I've also seen reports that the [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) AIX binary works on the IBM i using [PASE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm).

Comment: The Young IBM i Professionals (YiPs) have a section of their web site dedicated to PASE.  http://wsip-174-79-32-155.ph.ph.cox.net/wiki/index.php/PASE/PASE

Comment: @Buck and James, can you vote to reopen this question?